# Android: Should a database within an app be accessed in an asynchronous way?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, asynchronous

I'm making an app that uses a SQLite database to store data. Sometimes my app freezes when switching between activities that access the database, especially when the activity being started accesses the database in the onCreate() method.

Should I:

- Access the database using an async task or similar
- Use some kind of pipeline to control database requests?

Could you point me to relevant code samples if nessecary please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a better solution:

I am using a pipeline system, where I have runnables that are posted into the pipeline that get executed in the order they were posted. I find this solution easy to manage, neat and efficient.

An example of pipelining is here: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yor must use asynch access, this is best practice.
SDK contains AsynchTask especially for this.

```
BuyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Item, Void, Item> {
    @Override
    protected Item doInBackground(Item... params) {
        ..use DB here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ..some easy operation befor start thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Item resultTask) {
        ..do what you want, thread is finish
    }

}
```

Comment: How d you recommend I pass the values to update into the async task, as I need to say whether I wish to create, update, read or delete, and pass the data to manipulate the database with. Should I use a bundle?

Comment: Also, using an async task means I have to have an AsyncTask in every class I wish to use the database with, is this correct?

Comment: This is like command, that do one think. You may write InsertAynckTask, Update... etc., or you may use BuyAsynckTask, Sell.. etc. I think last is best solution. In onPreExecute you may get instance of your dbDAO, and use insert/update..etc in doInBackground.